# useState with dynamically generated nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

so I have dynamically generated nested object of structure as attached.
This object is being generated by 1st useEffect:

```
{
'DataStore': {
    'debug': true
},
'Header': {
    'debug': false
},
'Footer': {
    'debug': false
},
'Sidebar': {
    'debug': false
},
'Main': {
    'debug': false
},
```

There's a 2nd useEffect in this component which requires this data.
if I'm not misinformed you're supposed to useState hook to share the date between them.
Unfortunately I'm struggling to figure out the syntax to clone this object to useState
so than we can access it in 2nd useEffect

In essence this would be a simplified structure of the code:

```
const DB_Difference = useSelector(state => state.devMode.devMode);

useEffect(() => {           // useEffect that generates the object 
   
    DB_Difference generated here

    return () => {
        cleanup
    }
}, [dependencies])

    

useEffect(() => {       // 2nd useEffect 
    
    DB_Difference - needs to available here

    return () => {
        cleanup
    }
}, [])
```

please advise

Comment: as the code you've showed what happens is that the 2nd will probably run first (since it has no dependencies) and then the "first" will run and whenever "dependencies" change

Comment: you probably want to put `useSelector` inside the initial `useState` or inside a `useEffect` without dependencies that will both `setState` and be used on the second hook